# DNN - Creating Admin users for Child Portals

Tags: dotnetnuke, portal

I have a parent portal with a number of child portals contained within. My host user can access all of the portals, but when I create an admin user I cannot see the user (or it's new role) in the child portals. Is there a way to create an admin user that can update the contents of a module in all of the child portals (not the settings of the module)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify table "UserPortals", and add UserId for each portalid.

And also assign user with admin role on of each portal in table UserRoles, since each portal have different roleId for Administrators. (See table Roles)